# Z3: Grouping assertions and linking groups of assertions

Tags: z3, z3py

Let `c_1, ..., c_n`, `d_1, ..., d_n` and `e_1, ..., e_n` be assertions. Is it possible to group assertions and connect the groups instead of single assertions in Z3?

For example, let `C, D` and `E` be a groups, where `C` contains all `c_i`, `D` contains all `d_i` and `E` contains all `e_i`; the assertions of each group are connected with `AND`.

Is there a way to check the satisfiability of assertions as `IF C THEN D ELSE E`, where the model returns a configuration for `c_i, d_i` and `e_i`?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but isn't this as easy as defining C as and of c_1..c_n (same for D and E), and then asserting IF C THEN D ELSE E. Look at this z3 link http://rise4fun.com/Z3/eOqB for my SMTLIB2 encoding for n=3.